# biblatex: per-entry language switching

Tags: bibtex, biblatex, languages, hyphenation

According to `biblatex` manual (p.24), the hyphenation field in a bib-entry switches language on per-entry basis:

> `hyphenation` field 
>   The language of the bibliography entry. The identifier must be a language name
>   known to the babel package. This information may be used to switch hyphenation
>   patterns and localize strings in the bibliography.

This functionality seemed to not work. I just used an example of bib base that comes with `biblatex` documentation to print the entire bibliography.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The bibliography contains few entries in German. However in the printed list of references they are formatted with english strings.

> [8] Averroes. Drei Abhandlungen über die Conjunction des separaten Intellects
>   mit dem Menschen. Von Averroes (Vater und Sohn), aus dem
>   Arabischen übersetzt von Samuel Ibn Tibbon. Ed. and trans. by J. Hercz.
>   Berlin: S. Hermann, 1869.

Per-entry language switching is provided by the [GOST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/gost/) bundle of bst style for BibTeX.
Looking through `biblatex` internal code, I've got an impression that `biblatex` needs major re-implementation in order to provide similar functionality. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I removed the {biber} tag because I reckon that your question is not biber-specific.

Comment: @lockstep: And why is it bibtex specific?

Comment: @Herbert: The {bibtex} tag is also used for questions regarding `.bib` files (although these are not bibtex-specific anymore). I agree that this is somewhat awkward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides including hyphenation fields in your `.bib` file, you need to set the `babel` option of `biblatex` (presumably to `autolang=other`). See section 3.1.2.1 of the manual for details.

Comment: If you are testing with the `biblatex-examples.bib` you need to add british, spanish and french to the list of languages when you load `babel`. (Obviously not required if your own bibliography doesn't contain such language entries.)

Comment: The `babel` option now seems to be deprecated in favour of `autolang`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Desired result was obtained after I had modified the preamble of my example as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german,british,french,spanish,american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
style=numeric
,backend=biber
,babel=other
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
```

The reference 8 now reads as

> [8] Averroes. Drei Abhandlungen über die Conjunction des separaten Intellects
>   mit dem Menschen. Von Averroes (Vater und Sohn), aus dem
>   Arabischen übersetzt von Samuel Ibn Tibbon. Hrsg. und übers. von J.
>   Hercz. Berlin: S. Hermann, 1869.

Comment: from my point of view, it is not correct. The bibliography should be in the same language as the main document.

Comment: @Igor: Please consider marking my answer (or yours) as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count. Also, consider to choose an accepted answer for the other questions you have asked so far.

Comment: @herbert for example in ISO 690, some strings (like volume or edition) are in the language of a cited document, others, like pagecount are in the language of the main document

Comment: @michal: I know, but if I am the reader of the document, I want to read the bibliography in the same language, except the title.

Comment: @Herbert: in my contry bibliography by tradition is formated on per basis basis.

Comment: It still outputs it in English for me! What was the thing that made the difference? Here is my preamble:
  
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
 style=numeric,
 sorting=none,   
  backend=biber,
 babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[german,american]{babel}

\addbibresource{references.bib}