# multilingual references

Tags: cross-referencing, languages

Just for curiosity...

Is it possible to include into your references articles that are published in different languages?

Let's say for instance that one of my `biblatex` entries is written in greek, whereas the rest of them are in english.

How can i print my whole reference list that includes both the "greek" and "english" entries, using the `article` document class?

Comment: Assuming the languages employ alphabets that are derived from Latin, yes  would be the answer to the first question, and no the answer to the second.

Comment: but if the language is not a "Latin derivative" (e.g. greek alphabet, cyrillic, etc), then is it possible to have an multilingual list of references?

Comment: You'll likely need to load some font also language packages, but that'll be the case regardless of whether they're used in bin entries.

Comment: The `babelbib` package allows you to add a `language` tag to BibTeX entries, and formats/writes the bibliography according to the entry's language. Far from perfect (what of a paper in English, published in a French journal, whose authors happen to be Hungarians and Portuguese?), but workable.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was closed. Voting to reopen. Here's a related question.) [Hyphenation of bibliographies with multiple languages using xelatex,xgreek and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18740)

Comment: And another related question: [How to create multilingual (English, Japanese) bibliographies with biblatex, biber and polyglossia](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28010)