# How to use two different languages in the same bibliography with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Is it possible to mix two different languages in the same bibliography made with Biblalex?

I would like to get this output:
[image: Expected output]

Instead of this:
[image: Result]

I have tried using `langid` field, but it localizes only hyphenation.

`paper.tex:`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}

\begin{document} 
\cite{paperES, paperEN}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`biblio.bib:`

```
@article{paperES,
    author={Adan Cruz and Brisa Carmelo},
    title={Titulo},
    journal={Título de la revista},
    year={2011},
    volume={IV},
    pages={8-17},
    langid={spanish},
} 

@article{paperEN,
    author={John Smith and James Brown},
    title={Title},
    journal={Journal title},
    year={2012},
    volume={V},
    pages={3-15},
    langid={english},
}
```

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Apart from titles, the language of the bibliography should be the same as the language as the text of the paper you are writing. Is there any actual journal or style guide that requires this?

Comment: This is a strange requirement for bibliography in my university. I need to use ```and, In``` with English and ```y, En``` with the Spanish articles.

Comment: Amazing.  Universities can be the most ridiculous institutions at times. So if you had Hebrew and Japanese articles, would they also require Hebrew and Japanese version of 'and' and 'in' too?  What country is this in?

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you, I'll pass this on to my department. I'd prefer not to tell which country it is.

Comment: @niekas - Just ask your department what you should do if your bibliography has entries written in English, Spanish, German, Danish, Greek, Hebrew, Japanese, Chinese, and Thai... :-)

Comment: Anyway, this is a duplicate of [biblatex: per-entry language switching](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12224). Just add `\setotherlanguage{spanish}` after you set the main language and in your `biblatex` options add `babel=other`.

Comment: ```Package biblatex Warning: 'babel' option is deprecated, use 'autolang' instead.``` I was reading BibLaTeX v1.9 documentation, but Ubuntu package manager installed BibLaTeX v1.8.

Comment: You may want to replace the Ubuntu-provided TeX Live with the current upstream release: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) -- Ubuntu's and Debian's goal with a release is to keep packages predictable and consistent for years rather than introduce major new versions and the potential for variation in their install base.