# Is is possible to conditionally switch languages within one document?

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, languages

I'm quite new to `biblatex`. I'm typesetting a collection that has papers both in English and Russian, and I'm making a single bibliography at the end of the book.

For the bibliography to look pretty, the entries should be 'localized' individually. That is, I want an English book to come out as

```
Smith and Smith (eds.)
```

but a Russian one to come out as

```
Иванов и Иванов (ред.) [not "eds."!]
```

I have a very vague idea that it can be achieved with a conditional in some macro that'd check the `language` field of each given entry and select things accordingly. But I've no idea how to approach it --- just browsing `biblatex.def` lead me nowhere but here. I'm using `lualatex` for this, just in case.

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: The language field is important for hyphenation of, for example, the title. I am not aware that biblatex would suddenly chage the localisation strings, though this would be possible. On the other hand, this would make your bibliography impossible to read for a non-language speaker. Even the names would be better to additionally given in roman transliteration, i.e. Ivanov and Ivanov.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Sure, hyphenation would come in handy anyway, and it seems more economical to me to reuse the field compared to introducing a new custom one. On the other hand, transliteration is not a possible solution here (russian names are only referenced in papers in russian which assume some knowledge of the language:). It's in those entries that I need Russian abbrv -- otherwise they are transliterated, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better vice versa then? Instead having *eds* to have the russian equivalent? For *accessed* and others as well to have a consistent bibiography?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Sorry, I didn't quite follow that..:) What's vice versa in this case?

Comment: All strings in russion, and not in english for english entries and french for french entries. But the question, if or if not to do that, would be off topic here :-)

Comment: No answer to the question, but I'd like to point out that it is indeed not uncommon to have bibliographies that are not consistent in the way we are used to from BibTeX or biblatex.

In ISO 690 (Documentation -- Bibliographic References -- Content, form and structure) the standard is to leave lots of things untranslated, so in the same bibliography there can be a work that is "2. ed" and another that is "2. Aufl.", for example. At least in the Swedish translation/adaption of that standard which I've read. (There entries not written with a Latin alphabet would be transliterated, though.)

Comment: @pst Just checked, the german variation also mixes at some instances. I was looking in ISO 690 for a few days, and i wasn't aware of another language.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov You could try adding the `babel=other` option when loading `biblatex` and supplying the Russian-language entries with something like `hyphenation = russian`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [biblatex: per-entry language switching](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12224) I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most definitely not a complete answer but you could try adding the `babel=other` option when loading `biblatex` and supplying the Russian-language entries with something like `hyphenation = russian`. Whether there is a way of automating this latter operation is still an open question.

Comment: That works and is by far simpler than conditionals! Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can also give the `langid` field in addition to setting `autolang` to a sensible value.

Unfortunately, the mapping to the language is a bit picky and does not work with XeLaTeX (an utf8 aware engine) out of the box.

[image: ivanBiblatexLocale]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @online{someotherentry,
        url={texwelt.de},
        urldate={2015-05-11},
        author={a guy},
        translator={a guy},
        editor={a guy},
        langid={ngerman}
    }
    @online{onlineentry,
        url={some},
        urldate={2015-05-11},
        langid={russian},
    }
    @book{bookentry,
        editor={smith and Wesson},
        langid={russian}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman,russian,english]{article}
\usepackage[autolang=other,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{citeall}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{russian}{urlseen={Priviet},
%andothers={and some other guys}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\citeall[\fullcite]
\end{document}
```