# How to use both "et al." and other lang. "et al." in one bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, babel, biblatex-chem

I am using biblatex with custom biblatex-chem style in my paper like this:
`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew,articletitle,maxbibnames=5,minbibnames=4,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}` 
Also I use
`\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`
and I have literature in both languages. In my bibliography I want to have "et al." thing when citing foregin authors (latin names) and "и др." when citing russian authors (cyrillic names) but I have "и др." in every reference now.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,english,russian]{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,articletitle,babel=other,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

That example gives the log-file uploaded externally, or body is too long. http://hastebin.com/ukulotoren.tex

Comment: I think this answer i gave a while back might help [Is is possible to conditionally switch languages within one document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244337)

Comment: Thanks for help! I added `langid={english}` to my references and `babel=other` to biblatex options but nothing changed. Am i missing something? Maybe this happens because i use custom style.

Comment: Have you called biber and the whole chain once more?

Comment: No, i have not. And what exactly do you mean, after what i must do it?

Comment: You have just updated the database, that means you have to call biber to read the database and give it over to LaTeX. That means, you have to run LaTeX as well.

Comment: No, that's not the case.

Comment: Eugenie, what do you mean?

Comment: That means i do it every time anyway.

Comment: Your version of `biblatex` and other packages are very outdated. You should consider updating to TL 2014. And soon to 2015 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get proper code markup:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{bookentryA,
        editor={smith and Wesson},
        langid={english}
    }
    @book{bookentryB,
        editor={smith and Wesson},
    }
    @book{bookentry,
        editor={smith and Wesson},
        langid={ngerman}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[ngerman,english,russian]{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,articletitle,babel=other,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{citeall}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\citeall[\fullcite]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This MWE gives error:
File `citeall.sty' not found. \usepackage

Comment: @Eugenie No problem, that is for convenience in testing. Substitute it with `\nocite{*}\printbibliography`. The example is nearly the same as posted before.

Comment: All three are the same. I have this as output:
[1] (ред.: smith, Wesson).
[2] (ред.: smith, Wesson).
[3] (ред.: smith, Wesson).

Comment: Can you add the example you just compiled and tested to the original question along with the log-file? Maybe you have an old version and need an update.

Comment: Log: http://hastebin.com/ukulotoren.tex
Code: `\documentclass[ngerman,english,russian]{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,articletitle,babel=other,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}`

Comment: No problems with this code. I have: [1] (Eds.: smith, Wesson). [2] (ред.: smith, Wesson). [3] (Hrsg.: smith, Wesson). Perhaps the upgrade is really necessary.