# Change language on a per field basis

Tags: biblatex, hyphenation, polyglossia

I am creating a bilingual (main: greek, secondary: english) document with `xelatex` and `polyglossia` and I'm using `biblatex` with biber for the bibliography management. As biblatex is currently setup the bibliography is output in greek which is fine. However, since most of the bibliography is english, the bibliography fields are not hyphenated properly.

If I add `autolang=hyphen` to the biblatex options, the hyphenation is correct, but the whole entry converts to english which is something I do not want. Is there any way to change language on a per field basis only? For now I have created a simple macro `\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}` and add `\en` to the fields I want in english, but this is tiresome and error-prone on a document with way too many references. Is there any way to change the language of the specified fields (title, author, journal, booktitle) but not alter the language of the whole entry?

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

% Change these if you want
\newcommand{\MainFont}{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\SansFont}{Arial}
\newcommand{\MonoFont}{Courier New}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
  @article{anarticle,
    author={Lathrop, J.W.},
    journal={Electron Devices, IRE Transactions on},
    title={Photolithographic fabrication techniques for transistors},
    year={1958},
    month={April},
    volume={5},
    number={2},
    pages={117},
    doi={10.1109/T-ED.1958.14395},
    ISSN={0096-2430},
    langid={english},
    hyphenation={english}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\MainFont}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\SansFont}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\MonoFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\MainFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\SansFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfonttt[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\MonoFont}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{anarticle}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the `autolang=hyphen` option does exactly this: the bibliography will be in the main language, but hyphenation will respect `langid`

Comment: Maybe of interest: [Is is possible to conditionally switch languages within one document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244337)

Comment: you can try `language=autobib,autolang=other` or `language=autocite,autolang=other` you will see a difference. this is also ho to set manually fields. You will not need to set maunually in bbl or bib file: `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{%
 \iffieldundef{langid}
 {#1}
 {\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{#1}}%
}

\DeclareListFormat{location}{%
 \iffieldundef{langid}
    {#1}
 {\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{#1}}%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{institution}{%
 \iffieldundef{langid}
 {#1}
 {\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{#1}}%
}
`

Comment: and to set names and initials `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{\scshape #1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\foreignlanguage{\thefield{langid}}{\scshape #1}} 
` but you need to have langid fields in bib file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `autolang=hyphen` option does what you want.  Here's your example but I've made the margins deliberately large to show the hyphenation. Because of the very big margins this still results in some bad boxes, but this is to be expected.  For comparison, the example without `autolang=hyphen` is given also.  (I also corrected the month field to a numeric field, which is what `biblatex` prefers.)

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.8in]{geometry}
% Change these if you want
\newcommand{\MainFont}{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\SansFont}{Arial}
\newcommand{\MonoFont}{Courier New}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{anarticle,
    author={Lathrop, J.W.},
    journal={Electron Devices, IRE Transactions on},
    title={Photolithographic fabrication techniques for transistors},
    year={1958},
    month={4},
    volume={5},
    number={2},
    pages={117},
    doi={10.1109/T-ED.1958.14395},
    ISSN={0096-2430},
    langid={english},
    hyphenation={english}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,maxcitenames=2,language=auto,autolang=hyphen]{biblatex}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\MainFont}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\SansFont}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\MonoFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\MainFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfontsf[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\SansFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfonttt[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\MonoFont}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{anarticle}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

#### With the option

[image: output of code]

#### Without the option

[image: output without option specified]

Comment: This is the correct answer so I'm selecting it. I have found that there was a language switching statement before my bibliography, so it was my fault. I apologize.