# biblatex date string not defined with Greek and autolang=other

Tags: biblatex, errors, polyglossia, greek

In answering [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/260954/2693) I discovered some strange interaction between the `greek` language setting and setting the `autolang` option of `biblatex` to `other`.

As you can see from the output, the month gets output as **dateapril** because that bibliography string is undefined.  If I change the main language to something other than `greek`, e.g., `german` or `french` the problem does not arise.  But since the `autolang=other` option should be accessing the `english` date strings (as it does with these languages) it's not clear to me why when `greek` is the main language, the date string is undefined.

The following document reproduces the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{anarticle,
    author={Lathrop, J.W.},
    journal={Electron Devices, IRE Transactions on},
    title={Photolithographic fabrication techniques for transistors},
    year={1958},
    month={4},
    volume={5},
    number={2},
    pages={117},
    doi={10.1109/T-ED.1958.14395},
    ISSN={0096-2430},
    langid={english},
    hyphenation={english}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek} % works with german, french, etc.
\setotherlanguage{english}
% Change these if you want
\newcommand{\MainFont}{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\MonoFont}{Courier New}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\MainFont}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{\MonoFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\MainFont}
\newfontfamily\greekfonttt[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{\MonoFont}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxcitenames=2,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{anarticle}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turns out to be a bug in the `greek.lbx` localization file. Instead of using its already defined `\lbx@gr@mkbibmonth` to format the date, it instead uses `\mkbibmonth` defined via `\let\mkbibmonth\lbx@gr@mkbibmonth` after first using `\savecommand{\mkbibmonth}`.

Replacing the use of `\mkbibmonth` with `\lbx@gr@mkbibmonth` directly in the `.lbx` file solves the problem.  I have reported the bug to the author, and the fixed file will appear when the next update of `biblatex` is pushed to CTAN.

Answer (score 0):

Add in preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  dateapril = {April}
 }
```

Now result is :
[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question. The point is that English strings should be used for this entry, even though the main document language is Greek.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in opposite

Comment: I updated answer...yes there are 'dateapril' fields for other languages, but not for english...When user tryes to 'otherlanguage' I guessed biblatex tryes to find translation of appropriate fields in this case `dateapril` whan it does not find it if returns back to mainlanguage..this seems a bug

Comment: @LevanShoshiashvili Yes, this is a workaround (although you need to do it for all months). But the bug is induced by `greek.lbx` since other languages do not cause the behaviour.

Comment: @ AlanMunn , yes you are right . Just tested for other language as mainlanguage and there is no problem