# Textual citations in case of "thebibliography" environment

Tags: bibliographies, harvard-style

I am a newbie in LaTeX and I have a significant problem in my work: I need to write a document with bibliography. My problem is that I have different languages items in the bibliogrpahy, and I need to use different bibliogrpahy style for different languages. My idea is that I need to use `thebibliography` environment to solve this. It is working, but I need to use textual citations in the text (e.g. `(Einsten, 1922)`, Harvard citation style). How can I make textual citations in accordance with `thebibliography` environment? (I saw `natbib`, `bibtex` and `biblatex` but in these environments I can not make items in the bibliography with different styles...)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is unclear to me where you might have problems. Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References

Comment: You can use natbib along with a manual bibliography. See section "2.2. The Syntax of the thebibliography" in the natbib documentation.

Comment: It's usual that the formatting of the bibliography matches the language of the main text, not the language of the bibliography item itself.  But it is possible to use different formatting based on language if you use `biblatex`  so you should not have to resort to a manual bibliography to do this.  See [biblatex: per-entry language switching](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12224/2693)

Answer (score 4):

You can use natbib along with a manual bibliography. See section "2.2. The Syntax of the thebibliography" in the natbib documentation.

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\cite{jon90}, \citet{jon90}, \citep{jon90}



\begin{thebibliography}{90}

\bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{jon90} Jones et all, blblblbl
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]